# Why Vue Router not loading until i click link and reloads all webpage afterwards

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component, vue-router, reload

I got a components.js full of Vue.component instances.

Then i got a main.js where i have a router and i'm using the components to create the diferent pages.

At index.html i have the links to the router pages.

The problem is the first page load it's not loading the  template.
If i click Home link, nothing happens. But if i click About or Project, the page make a full reload. (Got an iframe with a prompt and it's showing again.)
Then, after click About or Project everything works as it should do.

I have tryied opening example.com/#/ manually in a new tab but it's the same.

main.js is like:

```
const About = { template: '<div>About</div>' }                        
const Home = { template: `                                            
<web-header></web-header>                                             
` }
const Project = { template: '<div>Project</div>' }

                        
const routes = [                                                        
{ path: '/', component: Home },                                       
{ path: '/about', component: About },                                 
{ path: '/projects', component: Project }
]                                                                                                                  

const router = new VueRouter({                                       
routes: routes                                                    
})
                                                                                                                           
const app = new Vue({
  router
}).$mount("#app");
```

Comment: You need to watch the routes.

Comment: Ohh, i'm a new using Vue. Where should i use the watcher?

Comment: Watch the routes, so as to react on route change 
E.g

`const Home = {
  template: '...',
  watch: {
    $route(to, from) {
      // react to route changes...
    }
  }
}`

Comment: Watch the route at every every file you registered on the route file

Comment: Still having the same problem.

Comment: How did you react to the changes, make a `console.log()` first to see if it outputs anything on navigation

Comment: Is not outputing anything if i click home. Does if i click on other page (and reloads). Also does if click back home...

Comment: I uploaded it here. Click Home at start and nothing happens. Also not loading home component. And if you click other link you get a full page reload. https://stringmanolo.github.io

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the root of the problem. Components where not loaded before use them.

Solution:
Add the components files BEFORE use them.

Valorations:
I'm used to add all my scripts before body closing tag.

In this case you have to add the component global instances files before head closing tag.
(Because html kebab sintax not working fine if you don't load components instances previously)

Now it's working fine.
Here you got a commit to view the changes i made.
(Just move the  tags)

https://github.com/StringManolo/StringManolo.github.io/commit/fcc331dc5136fb8a0da5a4c979ab67c8b85365e7